# phpmailer sending email via ssl: certificate expired

Tags: openssl, smtp, ssl-certificate, phpmailer, pear

I have written a new php script but I see some problem when I try to connect with server have a expired certificate:

1. I can use same smtp ip:port in windows program and its work fine.
2. I can use it and working with thunderbird but he give me certificate expired before send any thing

[image]

The code is below.

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: n0b0dy
 * Date: 11/1/18
 * Time: 9:40 PM
 */
require("/usr/share/php/libphp-phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
require '/usr/share/php/libphp-phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require '/usr/share/php/libphp-phpmailer/autoload.php';
require '/usr/share/php/libphp-phpmailer/class.smtp.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
/**
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
   'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => true,
        'verify_depth' => 3,
    )
);
*/
$mail->SMTPDebug = 4; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = 0; // authentication enabled
#$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
$mail->Host = 'ssl://75.101.161.108:465';
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->SetFrom("any@any.com");##### Dont care about email because of problem with connection 
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = "hello";
$mail->AddAddress("any@gmail.com");
if(!$mail->Send())
{
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
    echo "Message has been sent";
}
?>
```

and this is a problem for Phpmailer

```
2018-11-02 06:38:23 Connection: opening to ssl://75.101.161.108:465, timeout=300, options=array (
                                      )
2018-11-02 06:38:24 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server:  (0)
2018-11-02 06:38:24 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting%
```

B - pearemail with smtp setting and  code here

```
<?php
require_once "Mail.php";
include('Mail/mime.php');

$html = "TEST";// HTML version of the email
$crlf = "\r\n";
$headers = array('From' => "Test<example@any.com>",'To' => 'any@gmail.com', 'Return-Path' => 'example@any.com', 'Subject' => 'Form Pear Email');
$mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);
$mime->setHTMLBody($html);
$body = $mime->get();
$headers = $mime->headers($headers);
$smtpinfo["host"] = 'ssl://75.101.161.108';
$smtpinfo["port"] = '465';
$smtpinfo["auth"] = "false";
$smtpinfo["socket_options"] = array('ssl' => array('verify_peer_name' => false,'verify_peer' => false,'allow_self_signed' => true));
$smtpinfo["timeout"] = "10";
$smtpinfo["debug"] = "true";
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',$smtpinfo);
$mail = $smtp->send('any@gmail.com', $headers, $body);
if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
echo($mail->getMessage());
} else {
echo("WORKING\n");
}
?>
```

and related problem ,

```
DEBUG: Send: QUIT

Failed to connect to ssl://75.101.161.108:465 [SMTP: Failed to connect socket: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://75.101.161.108:465 (Unknown error) (code: -1, response: )]
```

i have use openssl with this command

```
openssl s_client -connect 75.101.161.108:465
```

result

```
  CONNECTED(00000003)
140527088361920:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1399:SSL alert number 40
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 176 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1541150392
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
---
```

So please, can anyone can help me ?

Regards for erveryone

Answer (score 1):

First step: you're using an old version of PHPMailer; [get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Base your code on the examples provided - in particular you should be using composer to load it, but with the old code you don't need to load classes *and* the autoloader.

The notice is bad. It's not just that it's expired, but that it's a mismatched name, expired, and not signed by a known CA. This suggests that your connection is being intercepted and redirected to somewhere other than what you're expecting. This is exactly what TLS is there to protect you from, and it is working as intended.

You should not disable certificate verification. Figure out what is happening to your connection (see the steps in the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide), and track down what your ISP does with outbound SMTP connections, then use openssl commands to inspect the certificate you're getting. We can't do any of this for you as you have hidden real host names.

Comment: i have lasts form phpmailer

Comment: No, that’s your PHP version, not your PHPMailer version.

Comment: sorry i understand u now yah i think u ask about php version 
i use phpmailer lasts to

Comment: it try all form PHPMailer troubleshooting guide

Comment: this one give me like it i dont know whats this 
openssl s_client -connect 75.101.161.108:465 
https://i.imgur.com/Qq1svWX.png

Comment: No you are not using latest PHPMailer. The current version files have different names to what you are using.

Comment: Add clarifications to your question, not in comments.

Comment: You need to use host names for openssl checks, not IP addresses, otherwise it cannot check certificate names against the host name, which is the thing that needs to match, and what allows you to detect interception. It looks like the server is misconfigured anyway.

Comment: thank you for help 
 i have add my clarifications to question

Comment: same thing when i use host name

Comment: Just looks like your mail server is broken. Fix that and your code can work.

Comment: if he broken why he work with anther program like 1st mailer and thunderbird ?
try u can see its working without any problem i dont know where is the problem 

stack-overflow have a pid work ??
if i want push money to fix this problem ?

Comment: You accepted the bad cert in thunderbird, the pear example allows bad certs, the PHPMailer code does not. It’s consistent.

Comment: yah i do it no way to accept it on PHPMailer ? that is bad news

Comment: Yes there is - same as for pear, and it’s covered in the docs, but you should fix your mail server.